# SignatureDoesNotMatch error when sending optional parameters to AWS S3

Tags: amazon-s3

I’m trying to use [getBucketObjectVersions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketGETVersion.html) operation with signature v4 to get the bucket object versions. If I don’t add any request parameters as  mentioned in the sample request below,  I am able to get the response successfully.

```html
GET /signv4testq23a1/?versions
Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=AKXXXXXXXXXXXEA/20171220/us-east-2/s3/aws4_request,SignedHeaders=content-type;host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date,Signature=fe3d26c4sdasdasd7fa15324XXXXX563dsf148df58d131b4cede6
x-amz-content-sha256: UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD
x-amz-date: Wed, 20 Dec 2017 07:22:14 GMT
Content-Type: application/xml
Host: s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
```

If I add any request parameters as mentioned in the sample request below I’m getting the SignatureDoesNotMatch error. Please note that the canonical request which is generated when calculating the signature is same as the canonical request expected by the backend service. But getting different hashed canonical request value expected in StringToSign value from backend service.

What could be the reason?

Sample request with request parameter:

```html
GET /signv4testq23a1/?versions&delimiter=/
Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=AKXXXXXXXXXXXEA/20171220/us-east-2/s3/aws4_request,SignedHeaders=content-type;host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date,Signature=192ce5f5e6b661bd5aXXXXXXXXXXXEAe5f50fbe8efda5a3e967d4f27972e 
x-amz-date: Wed, 20 Dec 2017 08:53:17 GMT
Content-Type: application/xml
Host: s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
```

Cannonical request:

```html
GET
/signv4testq23a1/
delimiter=%2F&amp;versions=
content-type:application/xml
host:s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
x-amz-content-sha256:UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD
x-amz-date:Wed, 20 Dec 2017 08:53:17 GMT

content-type;host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date
UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD
```

[enter link description here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketGETVersion.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem:

```
delimiter=%2F&amp;versions=
```

The keys and values should be url-escaped (encoded), but the `&` between parameters should not be escaped as `&amp;`... it should just be `&`.  You need to encode each key and value on its own, rather than the entire string once sorted and assembled.

> `CanonicalQueryString`
>
> specifies the URI-encoded query string parameters. You URI-encode name and values individually.
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-header-based-auth.html

Comment: If I use the & without escaping it I'm getting different canonical request expected from backend service. 

Generated canonical request:
GET
/1513162931643testconbkt2/
delimiter=%2F&max-keys=3&versions=
content-type:application/xml
host:s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com
x-amz-content-sha256:UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD
x-amz-date:Wed, 20 Dec 2017 13:40:03 GMT

content-type;host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date
UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD

Comment: Expected canonical request from the backend is(Returned in the error message):
GET
/1513162931643testconbkt2/
delimiter=%2F&amp;versions=
content-type:application/xml
host:s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com
x-amz-content-sha256:UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD
x-amz-date:Wed, 20 Dec 2017 13:40:03 GMT

content-type;host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date
UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD

Comment: From the first comment, how does the canonical request the back-end is returning differ from what your code is calculating?  Please use the edit button and provide additional content inside the question rather than comments when you are adding literal output or code -- it is difficult to read in comments.

Comment: Thanks Michael for the info. If I use the & without escaping, it works fine. The issue was in my previous comment is one request parameter was missing in the request.